# Use the data context as a method argument in LINQPad

Tags: linq, linqpad

I have a compiled assembly that contains a lot of my business logic rules which I would like to use inside of LINQ Pad.  I can add a reference to the assembly using `Query -> Query Properties`, but once I have the reference how do I access the context?

My BL object expects an `IMyDataSource` object, not an individual `IDbSet`.

Normally in a LINQ Pad query, the individual DB sets are "magically" available via their names.  For example

In normal .NET code I would write

```
Dim items As IQueryable(of Item) = DataSource.Items
```

but in LINQ Pad I would write it without a reference to the context.

```
Dim items = Items
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But if you're looking to qualify `Items` in your last line, you'd use `Me.Items`. The query is compiled into a subclass of the data source.

Comment: You've answered my question with `Me`.  It makes perfect sense now, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Want me to convert it to an answer? Or close it/leave it as is?

Comment: You should convert it to answer so I can accept it.  The key was that the query is compiled into a subclass of the data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LINQPad query is compiled into a sub-class of the Data Context, so your data source is available as `Me`. Therefor you can quality `Items` to `Me.Items` for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# inside LINQPad, you can refer to the Data Context as simply `this`. For example, you can refer to the entity collection `Items` as `this.Items` and get the same results.